# How to install QGIS 2.8/2.10 on Ubuntu 14.1?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.8

I have installed QGIS 2.0.1 on Ubuntu 14.1, yet I am not able to update to 2.8 or 2.10 since the proposed repository paths installations do not work. Anybody who can guide me through with a click instruction?

Comment: Hi Simon, Can you elaborate on "the proposed repository paths installations do not work"

Comment: I posted an answer here that contains installation instructions I've proposed to the QGIS team via github: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133033/installing-qgis-2-6-1-on-ubuntu-14-04/137079#137079 They still work well for me on Ubuntu, Mint, Lubuntu, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are running Ubuntu 14.10 (issued October 2014, hence the name!) which is also called Utopic.

So you can use either QGIS Debian repositories according to http://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu or the ubuntugis unstable repository https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntugis-unstable?field.series_filter=utopic. Ubuntugis has not yet published  QGIS 2.10, but has 2.8.1 as the latest.

Just follow the instructions to add one of the repositories (not both), and insert the code name Utopic stating your Ubuntu version.