# QGIS update from 2.14 to 2.16 failed on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: qgis, installation, ubuntu, qgis-2.16

Until yesterday my whole qgis and python-qgis worked fine with version 2.14 under **Ubuntu 14.04**.
After a simple `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` qgis failed to update... Several attempts to reinstall it with different versions failed.

Current error message (for version 2.14.3) goes like this:

```
qgis-providers (2.14.3+dfsg-2~trusty1) is configured ...
/usr/lib/qgis/crssync: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libgdal.so.20: undefined symbol: GEOSDelaunayTriangulation_r
```

I also tried to reinstall all gdal libraries - not sure if I got all?!

Maybe it is somehow related to this one: [QGIS 2.14 fails to install on Ubuntu 14.04](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183983/qgis-2-14-fails-to-install-on-ubuntu-14-04) ?

**UPDATE:**

Trying to install version 2.16.0 it gives different but similar error:

```
/usr/lib/qgis/crssync: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libqgis_core.so.2.16.0: undefined symbol: GEOSNearestPoints_r
```

**UPDATE Sources:**

For version 2.16.0 there are these sources in `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://qgis.org/debian trusty main
deb-src http://qgis.org/debian trusty main
deb http://qgis.org/debian trusty main
deb-src http://qgis.org/debian trusty main
```

which are all the same, right?

When I do `apt-cache policy qgis` it gives me:

```
qgis:
  Installiert:           1:2.16.0+20trusty
  Installationskandidat: 1:2.16.0+20trusty
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 1:2.16.0+20trusty 0
        500 http://qgis.org/debian/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.0.1-2build2 0
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: which version of ubuntu are you running?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 - just added it to the question. thx

Comment: What's your repository configuration? In other words, where is ubuntu trying to get qgis from? Look in /etc/apt/sources.list and sources.list.d/*

Comment: I also reported the bug on QGis Application System:
http://hub.qgis.org/issues/15307
maybe they can help as well?!

Comment: I have the same problem here. I used the qgis version based on the https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntugis-unstable repository. Tried both qgis 2.14 and 2.16 to install on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I don't believe qgis 2.14 or 2.16 is still available. Only qgis 2.18 is supported using the Debian repo: see for yourself here http://qgis.org/debian/pool/main/q/qgis/ The only 2.16 is unstable qgis_2.16.2+99unstable_i386.deb. There is no 2.14. This question is no longer relevant. Please try installing 2.18 (currently) and post back if you have problems.

Comment: You may still have problems with 2.14, or 2.16 -- but because the official packages in the debian repo have been yanked this bug can no longer be reproduced even if we cared to fix it (being old).

Comment: you are right - this question has no relevance any longer. I already changed to 2.18 (reinstalled system), so I voted to close as off-topic...

Comment: I just got this message in 2017 so this is not irrelevant to a user who suddenly gets such a message & is trying to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

On my machine

```
 Linux astun-desktop 3.19.0-32-generic #37~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 22 09:41:40 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

With the qgis.org repo set:

```
deb http://qgis.org/debian/ trusty main
```

The system update manager updated me to Qgis 2.16.0-Nødebo with no manual intervention from me at all.

Comment: I tried this to - see my update above

Comment: I've had two qgis 2.16 updates work fine on Linux Mint but the first one I just tried from Dell's stock Ubuntu broke qgis etc very badly (also installed a kernel with no networking support, but that's another story...). Problem with qgis seems to be libgdal2 related.