# QGIS removed after updating to 2.18.5 on ubuntu

Tags: qgis, installation, ubuntugis

After updating to QGIS 2.18.5 using ubuntugis ppa my QGIS 2.18.4 installation was removed and I get an error about unmet dependencies when I try to install QGIS at the terminal:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
python-qgis : Depends: python-future but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have seen similar posts like [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/220421/qgis-installation-fails-under-ubuntu-16-04) and [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202674/qgis-update-from-2-14-to-2-16-failed-on-ubuntu-14-04) on SE, but they were not able to resolve my issue. I have python-future installed in python 2.7, but I still cannot install QGIS. How might I resolve this problem? I have also tried installing the LTR, but this results in an even longer list of unmet dependencies. My OS is Linux Mint 17.3 (Ubuntu 14.04).

Comment: This is also a problem for me on Mint 18.1. It appears to relate to the gdal-abi-2-1-2 package. I think this relates to the most recent qgis update not having been compiled against the most recent gdal update in the ubuntu repos. My only solution way to get a working version of qgis was to revert to an older version of qgis (see the reply from @Raja here http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217727/broken-packages-and-unmet-dependency-installation-qgis-postgresql-and-postgis-u) and update your sources.list to point to the nightly updates in the hope the developers sort the issue quickly.

Comment: The same problem on Ubuntu 14.04  with http://qgis.org/debian ppa.

Comment: Well...upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04. Everything is working.

Comment: @AndreJ The Ubuntugis repo (current release) does indeed update to GDAL 2.1.3 just fine, but QGIS 2.18.5 (and several other associated packages) still fail because they depend on the virtual package gdal-abi-2-1-2, which isn't available. I'm stumped.

Comment: I also don't have enough reputation to comment, but I have the exact same problem as @scabecks: Mint 18.1 with latest updates and Qgis.org and ubuntugis unstable repositories for xenial. QGis 2.18.5 complains about the package gdal-abi-2-1-2, which isn't available. Is there already a follow-up thread as requested by @AndreJ?

Comment: @AndreJ Thanks for your help, on the QGIS bug pages too. I've re-asked this as a new question (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/233904/qgis-2-18-5-update-breaks-on-ubuntu-16-04) and have given responses/fixes based on your help. Add a a reply to the question and I can give you credit as it's very much due!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed a bug in the QGIS installer, and already has a ticket: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/16383

For the moment, only QGIS-LTR is running on trusty. You have to remove and purge the packages of QGIS 2.18 to avoid versioning conflicts: https://askubuntu.com/questions/187888/what-is-the-correct-way-to-completely-remove-an-application

Or consider upgrading to Linux Mint 18.1, which is based on xenial. The missing packages are available for that.

Installing python-future with pip does not help, since the package manager does not see that.

---

**UPDATE**

The ticket has been closed as fixed. Everything should be back to normal now.

Comment: You can also manually install python-future and python-owslib from http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/all/python-future/download and http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/all/python-owslib/download with dpkg, and then follow with upgrade. Note that those two packages will be left without updates (also security ones!)

Comment: But these are for xenial, not trusty.

Comment: It doesn't matter, as long as all of those packages' dependencies are met also in Trusty.

Comment: Following the instructions in the comment by pwes also did the trick for me on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Anyway, the repos should be fine now. The newer version of python-qgis does not depend on python-future or python-owslib, so you can remove the "obsolete" packages I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Following the instructions in the [comment by pwes](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/233605/qgis-removed-after-updating-to-2-18-5-on-ubuntu#comment364129_233694):

> You can also manually install python-future and python-owslib from
>   http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/all/python-future/download and
>   http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/all/python-owslib/download with
>   dpkg, and then follow with upgrade. Note that those two packages will
>   be left without updates (also security ones!)

I manually downloaded and installed the python-future package, and was able to install QGIS without a problem on my Mint 17.3 machine.