# Installation of QGIS on ubuntu 14.04 LTS trusty

Tags: qgis, installation, ubuntu, qgis-2.18

I am having the same problems as in those previous posts

- [QGIS 2.14 fails to install on Ubuntu 14.04](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183983/qgis-2-14-fails-to-install-on-ubuntu-14-04)
- [Installing the latest QGIS version on Ubuntu 14.04](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133033/installing-the-latest-qgis-version-on-ubuntu-14-04)
- [QGIS update from 2.14 to 2.16 failed on Ubuntu 14.04 [closed]](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202674/qgis-update-from-2-14-to-2-16-failed-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Though here the compilation failed with qgis 2.18.

I tried in my sources.list

```
deb http://qgis.org/debian trusty main
deb-src http://qgis.org/debian trusty main
```

as in post 2 above but I have dependencies issues. I then tried with

```
deb http://qgis.org/ubuntugis trusty main
deb-src http://qgis.org/ubuntugis trusty main
```

The installation failed at the configuration of `qgis-providers` with

```
/usr/lib/qgis/crssync: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libgdal.so.20: undefined symbol: GEOSDelaunayTriangulation_r
```

To solve this issue, I installed the latest gdal librairy, `gdal-2.1.2`.
The gdal lib comming with qgis was `libgdal.so.20.1.0`

This solved the above error, however the installation failed again when setting up`qgis-providers`, now with this error

```
/usr/lib/qgis/crssync: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libqgis_core.so.2.18.1: undefined symbol: GEOSNearestPoints_r
```

I also tried the installation with the unstable ubuntugis repository (ie qgis version 2.14) and got exact same problems. but apparently qgis 2.14 is not more supported according to the comments in post 1 above.

**EDIT 1:**

that's what I have been running

clean existing repositories

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ubuntugis
```

clean existing package

```
sudo apt-get remove gdal*
sudo apt-get remove libgdal*
sudo apt-get remove qgis*
sudo apt-get remove libgqgis*
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

in sources.list

```
deb http://qgis.org/debian/ trusty main
deb-src http://qgis.org/debian trusty main
```

then update and install

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis
```

which gives

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  gdal-bin grass-core libfreexl1 libgdal1h liblwgeom-2.1.2 liblwgeom-dev
  libqgis-analysis2.18.1 libqgis-app2.18.1 libqgis-core2.18.1
  libqgis-customwidgets libqgis-gui2.18.1 libqgis-networkanalysis2.18.1
  libqgis-server2.18.1 libqgisgrass6-2.18.1 libqgispython2.18.1 libspatialite5
  python-gdal python-pyspatialite python-qgis-common python-shapely
  qgis-common qgis-plugin-grass qgis-plugin-grass-common qgis-provider-grass
  qgis-providers qgis-providers-common
Suggested packages:
  grass-doc grass-gui grass-dev e00compr avce00 gpsbabel gpstrans python-rpy2
  xml2
The following NEW packages will be installed
  gdal-bin grass-core libfreexl1 libgdal1h liblwgeom-2.1.2 liblwgeom-dev
  libqgis-analysis2.18.1 libqgis-app2.18.1 libqgis-core2.18.1
  libqgis-customwidgets libqgis-gui2.18.1 libqgis-networkanalysis2.18.1
  libqgis-server2.18.1 libqgisgrass6-2.18.1 libqgispython2.18.1 libspatialite5
  python-gdal python-pyspatialite python-qgis python-qgis-common
  python-shapely qgis qgis-common qgis-plugin-grass qgis-plugin-grass-common
  qgis-provider-grass qgis-providers qgis-providers-common
0 to upgrade, 28 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 0 B/71.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 265 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Selecting previously unselected package libfreexl1:amd64.
(Reading database ... 1316497 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libfreexl1_1.0.0g-1ubuntu0.14.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libfreexl1:amd64 (1.0.0g-1ubuntu0.14.04.2) ...
```

... lots of Unpacking ...

```
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.2-0ubuntu3) ...
Unknown media type in type 'all/all'
Unknown media type in type 'all/allfiles'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mms'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmst'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmsu'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/pnm'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspt'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspu'
Setting up libfreexl1:amd64 (1.0.0g-1ubuntu0.14.04.2) ...
Setting up libspatialite5:amd64 (4.1.1-5ubuntu1) ...
Setting up qgis-providers-common (1:2.18.1+20trusty) ...
Setting up libgdal1h (1.10.1+dfsg-5ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libqgis-core2.18.1 (1:2.18.1+20trusty) ...
Setting up libqgis-gui2.18.1 (1:2.18.1+20trusty) ...
Setting up qgis-providers (1:2.18.1+20trusty) ...
/usr/lib/qgis/crssync: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libqgis_core.so.2.18.1: undefined symbol: GEOSNearestPoints_r
dpkg: error processing package qgis-providers (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Setting up gdal-bin (1.10.1+dfsg-5ubuntu1) ...
Setting up grass-core (6.4.3-3) ...
Setting up liblwgeom-2.1.2 (2.1.2+dfsg-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up liblwgeom-dev (2.1.2+dfsg-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libqgis-analysis2.18.1 (1:2.18.1+20trusty) ...
Setting up libqgis-app2.18.1 (1:2.18.1+20trusty) ...
Setting up libqgis-customwidgets (1:2.18.1+20trusty) ...
Setting up libqgis-networkanalysis2.18.1 (1:2.18.1+20trusty) ...
Setting up libqgis-server2.18.1 (1:2.18.1+20trusty) ...
Setting up libqgisgrass6-2.18.1 (1:2.18.1+20trusty) ...
Setting up libqgispython2.18.1 (1:2.18.1+20trusty) ...
Setting up python-gdal (1.10.1+dfsg-5ubuntu1) ...
Setting up python-shapely (1.3.0-1) ...
Setting up python-qgis-common (1:2.18.1+20trusty) ...
Setting up python-pyspatialite (3.0.1-4) ...
Setting up python-qgis (1:2.18.1+20trusty) ...
Setting up qgis-common (1:2.18.1+20trusty) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                            dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis:
 qgis depends on qgis-providers (= 1:2.18.1+20trusty); however:
  Package qgis-providers is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package qgis (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up qgis-plugin-grass-common (1:2.18.1+20trusty) ...
Setting up qgis-provider-grass (1:2.18.1+20trusty) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis-plugin-grass:
 qgis-plugin-grass depends on qgis (= 1:2.18.1+20trusty); however:
  Package qgis is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package qgis-plugin-grass (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                            Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.9) ...
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**EDIT 2:**

when following the same commands than in EDIT 1
but using in the sources.list

```
deb http://qgis.org/ubuntugis trusty main
deb-src http://qgis.org/ubuntugis trusty main
deb     http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu trusty main
```

the installation still crashes with `qgis-providers` but complains about gdal

```
/usr/lib/qgis/crssync: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libgdal.so.20: undefined symbol: GEOSDelaunayTriangulation_r
```

Comment: I wonder whether this and the three posts that you linked to should all be made into duplicates of a single canonical Q&A.

Comment: when trying to solve the decencies relationship, it looks like i have packages that cannot be installed with matching version. For example In my configuration I cannot installed `libgeos-c1`, `libgeos-c1v5`  and `libspatialite5` all together.

Comment: qgis.org/debian is compiled against GDAL 1.10. If you need GDAL 2.1.0, you **must** use ubuntugis. GDAL 2.1.1 is only available for Ubuntu 16.10, 2.1.2 only for debian testing, not from ubuntugis.

Comment: I added to the original post what I have been running. I solve the issue of the dependencies. I add a ppa of the stable ubuntugis repo that night have been there for quite a long time that was messing up things. installation is now stopping when processsing`qgis-providers`, see above.

Comment: try this. sudo apt-get install -f

Comment: @paugam try these - I just tested with a fresh copy of 14.04 and altered 'xenial' to 'trusty' and all worked just fine: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133033/installing-the-latest-qgis-version-on-ubuntu-14-04/137079#137079

Comment: @DPSSpatial I guess the solution lies in the **fresh** copy, since it works for me on Ubuntu 14.04 and Linux Mint 17.3 as well with the same commands.

Comment: @josego, did not work. same error

Comment: @AndreJ, yes agree. could that be linked with a dependencies of `libqgis_core` for example libgeos which seems to host GEOSNearestPoints_r?

Comment: Libgeos should have GEOSNearestPoints_r. I assume you have GEOS 3.4.2 and libgeos-c1when using qgis.org/debian. Strange thing is that it installs for me (and many others). Can you try installing ubuntu 14.04 and nothing else in a virtualbox?

Comment: why the installation is looking for GEOSNearestPoints in /usr/lib/libqgis_core.so.2.18.1 and not in some geos lib? yes I have `libgeos-3.4.2` installed. I am trying the fresh copy

Comment: GEOSNearestPoints is called in libqgiscore (qgsgeos.cpp), but not found in the linked GEOS library (geos_c.cpp). For the ubuntugis section, why have you left out deb-src for the ppa?

Comment: same as for DPSSpatial, it works fine with a fresh copy of ubuntu.

Comment: For the ubuntugis section I was following instruction from https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html.

Comment: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/# suggests the deb-src line too, but I don't know if omitting that harms anything. Anyway, if it works with a fresh copy for you, you can compare the file system of both. Maybe you have a lib file somewhere that does not get cleaned up by the package manager. Maybe related to http://askubuntu.com/questions/231562/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-get-purge-and-apt-get-remove

Comment: I did try to compare packages from the fresh xubuntu 14.04  and my 14.04 system with no luck. i guess it was time to switch to 16.04.

Comment: You have to look for individual files, not just packages.

Comment: I have same problem after installing matplotlib-basemap (https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/releases/), i compile geos version 3.3.3 from source, then my qgis cannot run. i'm looking in qgis website (https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html) it state that "since QGIS 2.8.x (due to dependency on GEOS 3.4 not available in precise)", i think this is dependency problem, then i remove geos 3.3.3, my problem fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The installation error seems to come from `libspatialite5`. There are two versions available for trusty:

- 4.1.1-5ubuntu1 from the main ubuntu repo. It depends on `libgeos-c1` and `libgdal1h`, and is used by `qgis.org/debian`
- 4.1.1-5ubuntu2 from ubuntugis ppa. It is compiled against `libgeos-c1v5` and `libgdal20`, and is used by `qgis.org/ubuntugis`.

Unfortunately, the libspatialite dependencies are not detected by the `qgis` packages.

You have to decide which path to install, and avoid mixing packages from both.

---

A clean install on a fresh Ubuntu inside a Virtual Box seems to solve the problem. On the host system, cleaning the system according to https://askubuntu.com/questions/231562/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-get-purge-and-apt-get-remove might solve the issue.

Comment: thanks. this solve the dependencies issue but not the Setting up of `qgis-providers (1:2.18.1+20trusty)`. still same crash as reported in first EDIT above

Comment: Can you remove libspatialite5, and try again?

Comment: did not work. it removes `gdal-bin grass-core libgdal1h libqgis-analysis2.18.1 libqgis-app2.18.1
  libqgis-core2.18.1 libqgis-customwidgets libqgis-gui2.18.1
  libqgis-networkanalysis2.18.1 libqgis-server2.18.1 libqgisgrass6-2.18.1
  libqgispython2.18.1 libspatialite5 python-gdal python-pyspatialite
  python-qgis python-qgis-common qgis qgis-plugin-grass qgis-provider-grass
  qgis-providers` and following installation crashes at the same stage `undefined symbol: GEOSNearestPoints_r`