# Invalid Data Source when importing geojson to QGIS

Tags: qgis, geojson

Im trying to import geojson, I add data, select protocol and use the uri https://d2ad6b4ur7yvpq.cloudfront.net/naturalearth-3.3.0/ne_50m_admin_0_countries.geojson QGIS says "Invalid Data Source: https://d2ad6b4ur7yvpq.cloudfront.net/naturalearth-3.3.0/ne_50m_admin_0_countries.geojson is not a valid or recognized data source"

I've followed the tutorial here http://webgeodatavore.com/add-geojson-content-in-qgis-short-recipes.html but I cant get the data to come in, any ideas? I'm using QGIS version 2.18.13

Comment: I have the same issue--Log Messages says: "Data source is invalid (SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate)"  And it looks like this issue (which was closed as invalid): https://issues.qgis.org/issues/16709

Comment: Do you have an  error on the OGR tab? https://i.imgur.com/oqq3vhL.png

Comment: I couldn't get it to load. I even tried ignore all cert errors, and tried several ssl protocol configurations with no luck.  https://i.imgur.com/021nDsD.png

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: Windows 7 .....

Comment: I also use Win7 at work.  But when I attempted on my Ubuntu 16.0.4...worked fine.

Comment: I have the same problem, I tried with 2.18 and 3.2 Q-GIS versions and nothing, I work in windows 10. If someone have more information about it would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Use the option Layer > Add Layer > Add Vector Layer

Then paste the URL into the Dataset box

It should render fine in WGS84 / EPGS:4326

[image]

Comment: I have done that exactly, also tried changing to protocol and utf-8, this is what I explain in my question, but I get the red error warning at the top of the screen. I'm using WGS84 EPSG:4326.

Comment: I got this to work without changing anything... weird! Can you save the file to your local drive and add it from there?

Comment: Downloading, and it works, I'd rather link to the repository geojson rather than having to have a local version. As above this is on windows 7, I will try on win 10 at work tomorrow.

Comment: I think this is an issue with QGIS SSL certs on windows.  Chrome is reporting the cert as valid ("Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4").  And QGIS ubuntu can load the same url with no issue.  btw, thanks @DPSSpatial for the https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/137079/31 answer...i was a bit behind and it isn't exactly intuitive as to how to raise qgis to a newer version.

Comment: Also, i did try an http link: http://cib.link/places.geojson and that loads into QGIS on windows successfully.