# Loading GeoJSON from github into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, geojson, github

Is it possible to load GeoJSON directly into qgis from github?

The GeoJSON is accessible here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/garynobles/data/master/sites.geojson

It displays fine if downloaded as a local file but I would like to be able to access it directly without having to download. I have googled around, but everything is about exporting to GeoJSON for github (i.e. keeping crs wgs84).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Its a HTTPS problem with qgis

Answer (score 10):

1. Click the "Add Vector Layer" button
2. Change "Source type" from "File" to "Protocol"
3. Ensure "Type" is "GeoJSON"
4. Paste in your URL
5. Click "Open" (or "Add" in QGIS 2.99dev/3.0)

The below pics are from QGIS 2.99dev (what will be QGIS 3.0) but 2.18 is basically the same.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply, that was the way I tried it in both 2.18 and 2.99, but I get: Invalid Data Source: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/garynobles/data/master/sites.geojson is not a valid or recognized data source

Comment: images added, the input and the error

Comment: @GaryNobles I've tested on 2.14, 2.18 and 2.99dev and it just works.  All the tests have been on Linux though and I see you're using Windows.  2 suggestions, 1. try changing the encoding from system to something else, 2. open the log messages panel and see if there's any extra info about the error.

Comment: I'm on my home wifi, doesn't usually have any issues, will try at work also.

Comment: Probably an SSL cert error https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/259394/2856

Comment: I'm recovering from a concussion, must be why I don't remember asking this question before, D'oh!

Comment: @GaryNobles haha I didn't notice that was your question :-) Hope you feel better soon.

Comment: Its a HTTPS problem with qgis