# Why is my QGIS installation not updating to a more recent version?

Tags: qgis, update

I've QGIS 2.18 installed in Ubuntu 16.04 for a long time. I added the repository https://qgis.org/debian.

Why is it not updating to version 3.0 or 3.2? I thought the respository for the LTR version is https://qgis.org/debian-ltr.

Comment: See this post, as you will need to upgrade your Ubuntu version before QGIS will upgrade: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133033/installing-latest-qgis-version-on-ubuntu/137079#137079

Comment: Ok, thank you so much for your comment @DPSSpatial!