# Linux Ubuntu 18.04 QGIS shuts down with no errors

Tags: qgis, ubuntu

Ubuntu 18.04, using this guide to install qgis on the machine. https://linuxhint.com/install-qgis3-geospatial-ubuntu/

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```

I can open QGIS and view layers but I cannot run any processes at all or save any layers. It just randomly shuts down with no error at all. when I click the about page it pops up for 1 second then QGIS closes completely.

[image]

I have also removed QGIS and reinstalled it multiple times with

```
sudo apt-get remove  qgis
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove qgis
sudo apt-get purge qgis
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove qgis
```

How should I go about troubleshooting this problem?

When I run `sudo apt-get update`

```
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Ign:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:4 https://qgis.org/debian bionic InRelease                                 
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]   
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Ign:8 http://qgis.org/debian codename InRelease                                
Hit:9 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83.2 kB]    
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB] 
Hit:10 http://qgis.org/ubuntugis xenial InRelease                              
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu bionic InRelease       
Err:12 http://qgis.org/debian codename Release                                 
  404  Not Found [IP: 104.27.138.220 80]
Reading package lists... Done                                                  
E: The repository 'http://qgis.org/debian codename Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Release file for http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 1h 11min 13s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
E: Release file for http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 31min 53s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
E: Release file for http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 31min 12s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list:59
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:58
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:58
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:58
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:58
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:58
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:58
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:58
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:58
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:58
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:58
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:58
```

then

```
apt-cache policy qgis
qgis:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:3.2.3+28bionic
  Version table:
     1:3.2.3+28bionic 500
        500 https://qgis.org/debian bionic/main amd64 Packages
     1:3.2.3+24xenial-ubuntugis 500
        500 http://qgis.org/ubuntugis xenial/main amd64 Packages
     2.18.20+dfsg-1~bionic1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     2.18.17+dfsg-1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
```

**UPDATE**

```
sudo apt-get update

Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83.2 kB]                                                             
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]                                                               
Ign:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                               
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                        
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]                                       
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main i386 Packages [140 kB]                                                        
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                       
Hit:9 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                                    
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages [355 kB]           
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages [177 kB]                                           
Hit:12 https://qgis.org/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                    
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main Translation-en [68.7 kB]                             
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [204 B]                               
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe i386 Packages [84.5 kB]
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 Packages [84.5 kB]                                      
Get:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages [394 kB]
Get:19 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe Translation-en [46.4 kB]
Get:20 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [6,848 B]
Get:21 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [9,088 B]            
Get:22 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [11.3 kB]           
Get:23 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main Translation-en [146 kB]
Get:24 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [170 kB]
Get:25 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [40.8 kB]
Get:26 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [76.7 kB]
Get:27 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted i386 Packages [3,600 B]
Get:28 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [3,648 B]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted Translation-en [1,376 B]
Get:30 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages [556 kB]
Get:31 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages [551 kB]
Get:32 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe Translation-en [143 kB]
Get:33 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [182 kB]
Get:34 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [170 kB]
Get:35 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [291 kB]
Get:36 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [5,392 B]
Get:37 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [5,540 B]
Get:38 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse Translation-en [3,124 B]
Get:39 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,464 B]
Get:40 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5,104 B]
Fetched 3,980 kB in 4s (1,079 kB/s)                                           
Reading package lists... Done
</pre>
```

added this `deb https://qgis.org/ubuntu bionic main` to the `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

tried running `sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis` and had the same problem as before

Comment: I suggest to update to QGIS 3.2. The Version 3.0 had many bugs.

Comment: @AndreJ how do I do that?

Comment: What do you get from `apt-cache policy qgis` ? Any packages held back when you do `sudo apt-get update` ?

Comment: Could you try these directions? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133033/installing-latest-qgis-version-on-ubuntu/137079#137079 I've got clean installs on Ubuntu and Mint with QGIS 3.2...

Comment: `http://qgis.org/debian codename Release` is surely wrong. You should replace `codename release` with `bionic main`. And `http://qgis.org/ubuntugis xenial InRelease` is wrong since you are running bionic, not xenial. Ubuntugis is not needed for bionic.

Comment: @AndreJ can you post the full commands I would need to use--the link that DPSSatial is confusing me with the commands. I cannot get it to work

Comment: The commands you run are ok, but you have to clean your sources list first. And I get no warnings during the `sudo apt-get update`. You should get QGIS 3.2.3 by installing now. Did you run `sudo apt-get upgrade` too?

Answer (score 1):

A tentative answer, too big to fit in a comment. I've not used Ubuntu for a while, but hope this helps.

```
apt-cache policy qgis
qgis:
 Installed: (none)
     Candidate: 1:3.2.3+28bionic
Version table:
  1:3.2.3+28bionic 500
    500 https://qgis.org/debian bionic/main amd64 Packages
  **1:3.2.3+24xenial-ubuntugis 500**
    500 http://qgis.org/ubuntugis xenial/main amd64 Packages
  2.18.20+dfsg-1~bionic1 500
    500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
  2.18.17+dfsg-1 500
    500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
```

Note that most of your dependencies are for Bionic, but not the one I highlighted.

Not sure if this is a packaging problem. The line that @AndreJ pointed out is certainly wrong. Check your /etc/apt/sources.list and comment out any references to ubuntugis

Whenever I hit problems like this in Ubuntu, I usually use [synaptic](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto) to nuke my settings and start over. Better still, try installing on a VM first :)

Answer (score 1):

The installation ist actually quite straight forward; @DPSpatial's linked post is a good source for instructions, and the QGIS Ubuntu/Debian download and installation instructions work out-of-the-box:

- First, purge your installation:

  ```
  sudo apt-get remove --purge qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
  ```
- and remove all relevant repositories from
  your `/etc/apt/sources.list`, e.g. by typing

  ```
  sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
  ```

  to open the *nano* in-terminal text editor, from which you can remove all entries that are connected to QGIS. It's only text, and you can always simply add missing/broken repos, but a little care is advisable (backup copy)
- Add the **proper** repository to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` (the
  blog you linked adds the *debian* repository, not the one for
  *ubuntu*!):

  ```
  deb https://qgis.org/ubuntu bionic main
  ```
- update *apt*:

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  ```
- install QGIS, pyqgis and GRASS plugin:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
  ```

---

Btw., from my machine, with up-and-running QGIS 3.2.3:

```
apt-cache policy qgis
qgis:
  Installed: 1:3.2.3+28bionic
  Candidate: 1:3.2.3+28bionic
  Version table:
 *** 1:3.2.3+28bionic 500
        500 https://qgis.org/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.18.17+dfsg-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: if you are getting keychain errors, you'd need to add the repo key. if so, say a word

Comment: `deb https://qgis.org/ubuntu bionic main` is surely wrong too. For bionic, you have to add debian bionic. for xenial, ubuntugis xenial. Ubuntu is not a valid option.

Comment: @AndreJ [this](https://qgis.org/ubuntu/) is the repo src for ubuntu, [here](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu) the package releases and distro versions supported.

Comment: Oh, someone did follow my advice ;-) But both folders still contain the same debian and ubuntu packages. You see it if you open the link in a browser.

Comment: tried these directions but had the same problem with the installation. I deleted any qgis repositories from my `/etc/apt/sources.list` added the proper one as you said `deb https://qgis.org/ubuntu bionic main` and ran through the setup process

Comment: @ziggy did you `sudo apt-get update` after you added the repo url?

Comment: @ziggy nevermind, I just realized you updated the question

Comment: could this have something to do with my geos and gdal installation?