# QGIS crashes upon launch

Tags: qgis-3, installation, linux-mint

I'm running QGIS on Linux Mint 19.3 and I just upgraded to the latest version following the instructions found at https://freegistutorial.com/how-to-install-qgis-on-linux-mint-19/

Opened up fine the first time, now crashes upon launch. When launching from the terminal, I initially got this message:

```
QGIS died on signal 11Could not attach to process.
If your uid matches the uid of the target process,
check the setting of /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope, or try
again as the root user.
For more details, see /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf
ptrace: Operation not permitted.
No thread selected
No stack.
gdb returned 0
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Following the instructions found at https://qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/bugreporting.html#bugs-features-and-issues
...I attempted to make a backtrace. Tried launching from the terminal again, and now I get this return:

```
using qt5ct plugin
D-Bus global menu: no
D-Bus system tray: no
QGIS died on signal 11[New LWP 4824]
[New LWP 4825]
[New LWP 4826]
[New LWP 4828]
[New LWP 4829]
[New LWP 4830]
[New LWP 4831]
[New LWP 4832]
[New LWP 4839]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
0x00007f5bd88f46c2 in __GI___waitpid (pid=4844, stat_loc=0x7ffccea7deac, options=0) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/waitpid.c:30
30  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/waitpid.c: No such file or directory.
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7f5bdd9223c0 (LWP 4814))]
#0  0x00007f5bd88f46c2 in __GI___waitpid (pid=4844, stat_loc=0x7ffccea7deac, options=0) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/waitpid.c:30
        resultvar = 18446744073709551104
        sc_cancel_oldtype = 0
        sc_ret = <optimized out>
#1  0x00005584e5f6c89e in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#2  <signal handler called>
No locals.
#3  0x00007f5bd94676da in QObject::property(char const*) const () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#4  0x00007f5b927cf657 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/styles/libbb10styleplugin.so
No symbol table info available.
#5  0x00007f5bdce226c6 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libqgis_app.so.3.10.2
No symbol table info available.
#6  0x00007f5bda4491cc in QListView::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#7  0x00007f5bda203048 in QWidget::event(QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#8  0x00007f5bda2a44de in QFrame::event(QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#9  0x00007f5bda417b8b in QAbstractItemView::viewportEvent(QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#10 0x00007f5bd943a6ac in QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendThroughObjectEventFilters(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#11 0x00007f5bda1c4815 in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#12 0x00007f5bda1cc104 in QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#13 0x00007f5bdb09f37b in QgsApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/libqgis_core.so.3.10.2
No symbol table info available.
#14 0x00007f5bd943a9c8 in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#15 0x00007f5bda1fc19a in QWidgetPrivate::sendPaintEvent(QRegion const&) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#16 0x00007f5bda1fc75a in QWidgetPrivate::drawWidget(QPaintDevice*, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#17 0x00007f5bda1fd3c0 in QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive(QPaintDevice*, QList<QObject*> const&, int, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#18 0x00007f5bda1fc366 in QWidgetPrivate::drawWidget(QPaintDevice*, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#19 0x00007f5bda1fd3c0 in QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive(QPaintDevice*, QList<QObject*> const&, int, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#20 0x00007f5bda1fc366 in QWidgetPrivate::drawWidget(QPaintDevice*, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#21 0x00007f5bda1fd3c0 in QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive(QPaintDevice*, QList<QObject*> const&, int, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#22 0x00007f5bda1fd549 in QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive(QPaintDevice*, QList<QObject*> const&, int, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#23 0x00007f5bda1fc366 in QWidgetPrivate::drawWidget(QPaintDevice*, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#24 0x00007f5bda1fd3c0 in QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive(QPaintDevice*, QList<QObject*> const&, int, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#25 0x00007f5bda1fc366 in QWidgetPrivate::drawWidget(QPaintDevice*, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#26 0x00007f5bda1fd3c0 in QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive(QPaintDevice*, QList<QObject*> const&, int, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#27 0x00007f5bda1fd549 in QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive(QPaintDevice*, QList<QObject*> const&, int, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#28 0x00007f5bda1fc366 in QWidgetPrivate::drawWidget(QPaintDevice*, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#29 0x00007f5bda1fd3c0 in QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive(QPaintDevice*, QList<QObject*> const&, int, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#30 0x00007f5bda1fc366 in QWidgetPrivate::drawWidget(QPaintDevice*, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#31 0x00007f5bda1fd3c0 in QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive(QPaintDevice*, QList<QObject*> const&, int, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#32 0x00007f5bda1fc366 in QWidgetPrivate::drawWidget(QPaintDevice*, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#33 0x00007f5bda1fd3c0 in QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive(QPaintDevice*, QList<QObject*> const&, int, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#34 0x00007f5bda1fc366 in QWidgetPrivate::drawWidget(QPaintDevice*, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#35 0x00007f5bda1fd3c0 in QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive(QPaintDevice*, QList<QObject*> const&, int, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#36 0x00007f5bda1fd549 in QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive(QPaintDevice*, QList<QObject*> const&, int, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#37 0x00007f5bda1fd549 in QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive(QPaintDevice*, QList<QObject*> const&, int, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#38 0x00007f5bda1fd549 in QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive(QPaintDevice*, QList<QObject*> const&, int, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#39 0x00007f5bda1fd549 in QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive(QPaintDevice*, QList<QObject*> const&, int, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#40 0x00007f5bda1fd549 in QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive(QPaintDevice*, QList<QObject*> const&, int, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#41 0x00007f5bda1fd549 in QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive(QPaintDevice*, QList<QObject*> const&, int, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#42 0x00007f5bda1fd549 in QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive(QPaintDevice*, QList<QObject*> const&, int, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#43 0x00007f5bda1fd549 in QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive(QPaintDevice*, QList<QObject*> const&, int, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#44 0x00007f5bda1fd549 in QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive(QPaintDevice*, QList<QObject*> const&, int, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#45 0x00007f5bda1fd549 in QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive(QPaintDevice*, QList<QObject*> const&, int, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#46 0x00007f5bda1fd549 in QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive(QPaintDevice*, QList<QObject*> const&, int, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#47 0x00007f5bda1fd549 in QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive(QPaintDevice*, QList<QObject*> const&, int, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#48 0x00007f5bda1fd549 in QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive(QPaintDevice*, QList<QObject*> const&, int, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#49 0x00007f5bda1fd549 in QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive(QPaintDevice*, QList<QObject*> const&, int, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#50 0x00007f5bda1fc366 in QWidgetPrivate::drawWidget(QPaintDevice*, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#51 0x00007f5bda1d3e64 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#52 0x00007f5bda1d4602 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#53 0x00007f5bda21fd4e in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#54 0x00007f5bda22066d in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#55 0x00007f5bda1c483c in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#56 0x00007f5bda1cc104 in QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#57 0x00007f5bdb09f37b in QgsApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/libqgis_core.so.3.10.2
No symbol table info available.
#58 0x00007f5bd943a9c8 in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#59 0x00007f5bd9a0249f in QGuiApplicationPrivate::processExposeEvent(QWindowSystemInterfacePrivate::ExposeEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#60 0x00007f5bd9a030dd in QGuiApplicationPrivate::processWindowSystemEvent(QWindowSystemInterfacePrivate::WindowSystemEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#61 0x00007f5bd99da2eb in QWindowSystemInterface::sendWindowSystemEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#62 0x00007f5ba0caf260 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#63 0x00007f5bcd414417 in g_main_context_dispatch () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
No symbol table info available.
#64 0x00007f5bcd414650 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
No symbol table info available.
#65 0x00007f5bcd4146dc in g_main_context_iteration () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
No symbol table info available.
#66 0x00007f5bd949397f in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#67 0x00007f5bdccb3821 in QgisApp::QgisApp(QSplashScreen*, bool, bool, QString const&, QString const&, QWidget*, QFlags<Qt::WindowType>) () from /usr/lib/libqgis_app.so.3.10.2
No symbol table info available.
#68 0x00005584e5f6812e in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#69 0x00007f5bd8831b97 in __libc_start_main (main=0x5584e5f66180, argc=1, argv=0x7ffccea838d8, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7ffccea838c8) at ../csu/libc-start.c:310
        self = <optimized out>
        __self = <optimized out>
        result = <optimized out>
        unwind_buf = {cancel_jmp_buf = {{jmp_buf = {0, 1609590866114588378, 94029282196912, 140723775617232, 0, 0, 4802593000917642970, 4893179368385752794}, mask_was_saved = 0}}, priv = {pad = {0x0, 0x0, 0x7f5bdd788733 <_dl_init+259>, 0x7f5bdd73f158}, data = {prev = 0x0, cleanup = 0x0, canceltype = -579303629}}}
        not_first_call = <optimized out>
#70 0x00005584e5f6bdda in _start ()
No symbol table info available.
gdb returned 0
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I'm guessing this is the backtrace. I'm a newbie to QGIS and am not a programmer, so could someone to tell me what this means and what I might need to do please. Before anyone asks, yes, I already tried reinstalling.

EDIT=====================================================================

Output from: `wget -O - https://qgis.org/downloads/qgis-2019.gpg.key | gpg --import`

```
gpg: keybox '/home/crossgear/.gnupg/pubring.kbx' created
--2020-01-28 17:41:21--  https://qgis.org/downloads/qgis-2019.gpg.key
Resolving qgis.org (qgis.org)... 2606:4700:3035::681b:8adc, 2606:4700:3030::681b:8bdc, 104.27.139.220, ...
Connecting to qgis.org (qgis.org)|2606:4700:3035::681b:8adc|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1839 (1.8K) [application/pgp-keys]
Saving to: ‘STDOUT’

-                                 100%[============================================================>]   1.80K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2020-01-28 17:41:22 (20.4 MB/s) - written to stdout [1839/1839]

gpg: key 51F523511C7028C3: 1 signature not checked due to a missing key
gpg: /home/crossgear/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 51F523511C7028C3: public key "QGIS Archive Automatic Signing Key (2019) <qgis-developer@lists.osgeo.org>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
```

Comment: Those instructions look like an out-of-date version of what we've been maintaining on an answer on this forum https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133033/installing-latest-qgis-version-on-ubuntu/137079#137079 I would give those a try and see if you get different results.

Comment: Additionally, I just spun up a virtual machine with Mint 19.3 and used the instructions I linked above line by line and they worked just fine, QGIS 3.10 came up no problem (make sure to use 'bionic' for the 'codename' in those instructions).

Comment: Would have never thought to look there given how old that post is. Sadly, they didn't work for me. Results look to be the same. Might be worth noting that I had already added the qgis repositories, so there are now two copies of each repository link in the sources file. Provided outupt from the "wget" command line above. I don't think it likes the key for some reason.

Comment: I would think the sources could be fixed manually - synaptic package manager or nano... could be worth doing a full purge then attempt again? Keep in touch tho.