# Installing QGIS on Debian only gets the LTR

Tags: qgis, debian

I am trying to install QGIS 3.10.2 on Debian Testing. I read the [install instructions](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu) and have updated my apt sources.list file to:

```
deb https://qgis.org/debian buster main
deb-src https://qgis.org/debian buster main
```

There is no bullseye or testing distro in the repository, so I defaulted to buster; I have also tried using unstable. I have purged previous installs of grass and qgis.

When I install QGIS after updating `apt`, it only installs the LTR (3.4.15). Any suggestions?  (I have also tried using the nightly build repo to no avail.)

Comment: Do these instructions work? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133033/installing-latest-qgis-version-on-ubuntu/137079#137079

Comment: No. Those instructions basically describe what I am doing already. I set my sources.list to what should be the newest repo, but I still get the LTR.

Comment: Using that repository you should be getting version 3.10. If you switched it to debian-ltr as per the QGIS.org instructions, you would get v 3.4. The instructions I posted above will give you version 3.10

Comment: @DPSSpatial: What you say is what I expected but did not observe. I am working with four Debian-based Linux machines, one on Buster (stable), and three on Bullseye (testing). The stable machine installed 3.10 no problem. The testing machines all refuse to upgrade (these three also all had the LTR version installed subsequently, but purged before attempting to install 3.10).

Comment: Instead of using 'buster' in the repository name I think you should be using the 'bionic' repository... could you try that instead? I don't know if the 'buster' version is fully functioning yet...

Comment: The buster repo does work for my buster machine. I can change the testing machines to the ubuntu repo, but when I do, 'The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 qgis : Depends: gdal-abi-2-2-3 but it is not installable
        Depends: libgdal20 (>= 1.8.0) but it is not installable
        Depends: libqgis-analysis3.10.2 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libqgis-app3.10.2 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libqgis-core3.10.2 but it is not going to be installed
...
'

Comment: Note that I have installed libgdal26 and libproj15, both of which seem to be ahead of what QGIS is looking for.