# Updating QGIS in Ubuntu 22.04.01

Tags: qgis, update, repository

Trying to update QGIS I followed the instructions here [Stack Exchange question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133033/installing-latest-qgis-version-on-ubuntu)

but the command`cat /etc/upstream-release/lsb-release` fails because there is no folder of that name.  Without this the addition of correct repository is impossible. Is there another way to find this information?.

Comment: Try with `cat /etc/*-release` or directly `cat /etc/lsb-release`

Comment: cat /etc/lsb-release Works perfectly.  Must make a note of that.